# Creation of google apps for education accounts in bulk

Tags: google-classroom

I know that we can create google apps for education accounts in bulk through admin console by uploading a CSV file, but I want to do that by using classroom API. Does the classroom API has that capability? if so how can I ? if not is there any way easier than doing through admin console ?

Assume that I have google apps for education domain.

Answer (score 1):

The [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/) does not provide the ability to create accounts.

You can use the Directory API for this though; see the [create a user account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) docs.

Answer (score 0):

The Classroom API is a low level programming interface and can not handle CSV processing on it's own. However, writing an app that uses the API to create courses based on a CSV is trivial. My app, [GAM](http://git.io/gam) can [create courses](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/Managing-Google-Classroom#creating-a-course) via Classroom API and supports [bulk CSV operations](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/BulkOperations#using-csv-files).